# How to hide a Google Spreadsheet from other users?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Spreadsheet which I share with my coworkers. I want to hide this document from others only when I'm editing it so they can't see what I'm changing. Is there any way to do this using Apps Script functions?

Comment: Yes, but without know the fine details it is hard to give pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can hide Spreadsheet document from others by using *hideSheet()* method.

Here's a sample code snippet below:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.hideSheet();
```

To view all listed method for Class Sheet, [follow the link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#protect()).